# Strange Kotlin null-safe behavior

Tags: kotlin

If global property is defined as `private var raceLoadJob: Job? = null` then Kotlin will ask you to do something like this in your method

```
if (raceLoadJob != null){
    if (raceLoadJob!!.isActive) return // null assertation
}
```

Kotlin will ask for assertation, because raceLoadJob value can be changed. The first thing I thought about is multi-threading.

So you can change code to

```
raceLoadJob?.let {
    if (it.isActive) return
}
```

But if you decompile this part of code you will see

```
Job var10000 = this.raceLoadJob;
if (this.raceLoadJob != null) {
   Job var1 = var10000;
   if (var1.isActive()) {
      return;
   }
}
```

You can see, that condition is `this.raceLoadJob != null`, but not `var10000 != null`. It means that in theory this code can fail because of `raceLoadJob` value is assigned, but var10000 is `null`.

Is this an issue or I have an error in my reasoning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error in your reasoning is that you're analyzing the behavior of Kotlin code by looking at the decompiler output and not at the bytecode. The Kotlin compiler generates patterns of bytecode which are not used by javac, so the decompiler (which was designed to decompile javac output) can only provide an approximate representation of the actual logic.

If you look at the actual bytecode, it looks like this:

```
ALOAD 0
GETFIELD raceLoadJob : LRaceLoadJob;
DUP
IFNULL L1
ASTORE 2
```

It shows that the value being checked for null is exactly the same that is being used in subsequent computations.